# Unable to unlock a SSD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, bios, passwords

I own a laptop Asus K56CA. Shortly after I bought it, I swapped out 5400rpm drive for a Samsung SSD 840. I’ve set up passwords: BIOS Administrator and User; also Master and User HDD Password.
Now, the operating system on my laptop got corrupted few days ago and I need to migrate Windows 8 from the original Hitachi 5400rpm drive to my Samsung SSD 840 (as I did it the first time).

To do this I need to remove the SSD 840 and put back the Hitachi drive into the laptop. The SSD must be unlocked, though. 
When I’m in BIOS to unlock it I can't change anything except the User passwords (BIOS and HDD). When I try removing the Master HDD password, it says, “Password can’t be cleared in User Mode”, even though, it also is written in BIOS that if I get into the setup the user will have Administrator rights.

I’ve taken few images of the BIOS and I’m attaching to this post.

Please, if anyone can help me with a way I should approach this problem, I’d really appreciate it.

PS. It’s my laptop and the Samsung SSD. I bought them on Amazon, so I’ve got that documented online, and in paper. I also have all the required passwords.

Comment: Something similar happened at my workplace at one point... we set a master password (no user password) and when we enter bios, it never asked for password, so we always ended up in Bios as User and can't do anything. At that time, we cold shutdown the laptop (press and hold power button for about 5-10 seconds until it is off completely), leave it off for about 1 minute, and start. Finally it asked for password when entering bios, so we can enter as Admin. If you know the Bios Admin password, use that, and most likely you can clear the master HDD password.

Comment: Unfortunately, attempting to reset BIOS hasn't fixed it.

Comment: You said you have the bios Admin password, can you login into the bios using the Admin password? Usually if you are in as Bios Admin (not user) you should be able to reset the password.

Comment: Indeed I have both passwords. The problem is that I only am asked for BIOS User password, and never for Admin password.